# Soft question on notation regarding partial bijections

Tags: category-theory, partial-functions

I'm not sure if the following technicality should just be ignored, or if I should just learn more category theory (of which I know very little), but here it goes anyway.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category whose objects are sets and whose morphisms are partial functions between sets. It is my understanding that that a *proper* partial bijection $f:X \to Y$ is technically not an isomorphism between its source and target (it would have to be a total function to qualify as an isomorphism). Therefore writing $f^{-1}$ to stand for the proper partial bijection $Y \to X$ that we would intuitively call the "inverse"
$$\{(y,x):(x,y) \in f\}$$
of $f$ conflicts with categorical terminology as it suggests $f$ is an isomorphism and invertible in $\mathcal{C}$, which is technically untrue.

Is there special notation that is used to denote the intuitive "inverse" of a proper partial bijection $f$, or maybe a special property of morphisms that encodes this weaker sense of "invertibility"? At the very least, do most people write $f^{-1}$ anyway, despite the technicality that $f$ is not an isomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for notation for the *inverse relation* of the relation $f$ (which happens to be a partial function).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_relation) lists the following: $f^{-1}, f^C, f^T, f^\sim, f^\circ$ etc. The book "Categories, Allegories" uses $f^\circ$ for example.

Also consider that the category with sets as objects and relations as morphisms can be made into a [dagger category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger+category) by equipping it with "taking the inverse relation", so $f^\dagger$ is also reasonable notation.

Take your pick (though I *personally* wouldn't recommend $f^{-1}$ for the reason you already gave).

Comment: I was aware of the concept of the inverse of a relation $R$ but I wasn't aware of notation for said inverse other than $R^{-1}$. Thanks for providing me with alternatives

Comment: So I went through all the basic results regarding the category $\mathsf{Rel}$ and the dagger functor, and what you directed me to was exactly what I was looking for, so thanks again. For what it's worth, my post was prompted by my annoyance with the delicate details regarding domains and repeated composition with coordinate charts for differentiable manifolds and coordinate representations of maps between manifolds. A few results from category theory really removes most of the burden.

Comment: Sure, no problem. - In my experience a bit of category theory can really help to see quickly what really matters about a notion in some unknown area that you are looking into.

Comment: One more question: is there a special name for a morphism $f:X \to Y$ in $\mathsf{Rel}$ that is a partial bijecton - that is, a left and right definite relation, or a relation $f$ such that $f^\dagger \circ f $ and $f \circ f^\dagger$ are inclusion maps, but not necessarily the respective identity maps on $X,Y$? Not being left or right total disqualifies a proper partial bijection from being a monomorphism or epimorphism, I think.